# How to write a regex to capture all the words with capitalized letter except one

Tags: regex

How to write a regex to match all the words with capitalized letter, but not match the BackGround in "a.BackGround = 1".

For example,

> I have FireFox and Safari. And I set a.BackGround =1

In the above sentence, I want to match **FireFox**, **Safari**, **I** and **And**, but not **BackGround**.

Comment: What is the criteria to not match `"a.BackGround = 1`?

Comment: Because I want to keep the code snippet as it is.

Comment: In your example, why not match `I` and `And`?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Is this sufficient:

```
(?:^|\s)([A-Z]\S*)
```

The word is in group 1.

Comment: if you want to select more than 3 alphabet in a word then you can use this if you want (?:^|\s)[A-Z]\w{3,} in this I & And is not selected with a.BackGround=1

Comment: The \S will also select a "." character. According to the question, any thing that resembles code (for example, "A.Background") should not be matched. Replacing \S with \w should do the trick.

Comment: @diveshpremdeep:It isn't said in the question that `A.` mustn't be match.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how well this will apply to other situations, but so far this is all the information you have given us.

This will match the words themselves, no need for capture groups, unless you so choose to use them:

> [**`(?<=\s|^)[A-Z]\w*`**](http://regex101.com/r/gL1hH9)

If the match is more complex, or applies to more than just the sample text you gave us, please let me know.